# ASP.NET Web Api built from/with Console

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, console

I want to be able to use an `ASP.Net Web Api` that opens and outputs to the `Console`.

The reason why is because I am initializing a lot of elements and objects before launching the Web Api. Then I register those objects with dependency injection to access them within my `ApiController`.

When I launch the Web Api, I need the Console to open so I can see how things are being initialized and how long does it takes.

I know it is possible to send logs from the Web Api to the debug console but this isn't what I want.

Maybe there is a way to start a console project and incorporate the Web Api framework into it ?

Comment: There are a number of logger packages (NLog being one) that can output logs to various destinations, such as files, console, databases, TCP/IP connections (and debug window too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWIN way:

1. Create a Console App
2. Add "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost" package and its dependencies to the project
3. Add Startup.cs file with the following content:

   ```
   using Owin;
   using System.Web.Http;

   namespace YourConsoleAppProjectNamespace {
       public class Startup {
           public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) {
               HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
               config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi",
                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
               appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Modify your project's Main()

   ```
   using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
   using System;

   namespace YourConsoleAppProjectNamespace {
       class Program {
           static void Main(string[] args) {
               WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:3333/");
               Console.ReadLine(); // block main thread
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Define a controller with action method and test.

Comment: Seems to be a cool solution. However the `WebApp.Start` throws a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Have you updated all versions of Owin-related packages after adding Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost 5.2.6? I have to update additionally 4 packages to their latest version.

Comment: I tried to, it said everything is up to date. But I have warnings, because I am running VS on a Mac, so its use NetCore App 2.1

Comment: Found the issue. Had to install `System.Configuration.Abstractions`.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/196

Comment: My test project targets .NET 4.6.1. The test project I created is of Console App(.NET Framework) type.